# Rails 4.2.2 - 5.0.0.1 diff cable.js issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diff, updates

I decided to consult [railsdiff.org](http://railsdiff.org/) in order to update rails 4.2.2 to 5.0.0.1

However, after update and running tests, I was warned about some issues. 
Line 6 of `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js` in `Rails 4.2.2 - 5.0.0.1 diff` raises an error (`channels` should be a directory). Line 6 is:

`//= require_tree ./channels`

Also, according to Cloud9 editor, `ActionCable` in `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js` results not defined: `ActionCable is not defined; please fix or add /*global ActionCable*/`

Did [railsdiff.org/4.2.2/5.0.0.1](http://railsdiff.org/4.2.2/5.0.0.1) miss anything, like a `channels` directory in `app/assets/javascripts` or the definition somewhere of an `ActionCable` class?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `railsdiff` does not consider and report empty directories. 
In `rails 5.0.0.1`, compared to `rails 4.2.2`, there are two new empty directories with an hidden, empty `.keep` file inside each one:

```
app/assets/javascripts/channels/
test/fixtures/files/
```

Line 6 of `app/assets/javascripts/cable.js` refers to `app/assets/javascripts/channels/`. 
Running the test suite without adding the `channels` directory would raise an error.